# Why Is My Subtraction Result Incorrect?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, azure-sql-database

```
select sum(l.coins) - sum(t.coins) as total
from luxx_getaway_2016_coins l
join thrive_rewards_redeemed t
on l.consid = t.guideid
where l.consid = 24969 and t.harvestyear = 1516
```

Hello all. I am attempting to grab an updated total using the query above. The problem I'm having is that the total of these sums totals out to well above what it should be. I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong. We're using Azure SQL Database and I've used RazorSQL and SSMS 2012 to run this query with identical results. Any help is appreciated. Please feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: What is returned if you just select the rows, without the sum?  e.g. `select * from luxx_getaway_2016_coins l
join thrive_rewards_redeemed t
on l.consid = t.guideid
where l.consid = 24969 and t.harvestyear = 1516`

Comment: Are `l.consid` and `t.guideid` unique in their respective tables? if not, you will get duplicates when you join.

Comment: @APH A list of all of the fields from both tables. I can now see why I'm getting the total I'm getting. For every line item in one table a duplicate line item is created for the table that is being joined. So if I have 10 rows in one table and one row in another, the one with the least rows needs to produce as many rows as the other table is producing.

Comment: @rdbradshaw I'm realizing that now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @rdbradshaw is this impossible in sql server under these conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to your duplication problem:

```
Select
    (select sum(l.coins)
    from luxx_getaway_2016_coins l
    where l.consid = 24969)

-
    (select sum(t.coins)
    from thrive_rewards_redeemed t
    where t.guideid = 24969 
        and t.harvestyear = 1516)
```

For the more general case:

```
; With A as (select consid, sum(l.coins) as TotA
    from luxx_getaway_2016_coins l
    group by consid)
, B as (select guideid, sum(t.coins) as TotB
    from thrive_rewards_redeemed t
    where t.harvestyear = 1516
    group by guideID)

Select a.consid, TotA - TotB as Total 
from A
inner join B
on a.Consid = b.GuideID
```

Comment: This worked for this query. Thank you. My next step is to figure out how to apply this principle and make a view with coins for all consid's.

Comment: @acecabana - I have edited the answer to show one way to do this with the general case.  I'm not at my main computer right now, so haven't tested it.

Comment: Any way to apply a full join and not have it show null values for non matching rows? I'd like to do the subtraction for ids that exist in both tables but preserve all records from table a along with the updated totals from the subtraction.

Comment: Yes; the query should work more or less the same if you change the `inner join` to an `outer join`.  Just add some `ISNULL`s as needed.